How to balance this redox reaction: Fe(NO₃)₂ --> Fe₂O₃ + NO₂↑ + O₂↑ (electronic balance)?
How can I balance such kind of chemical equation:
$$\ce{Fe(NO3)2 -> Fe2O3 + NO2↑ + O2↑}$$

You should tell us what you know on the matter, so that we know where to start.

It is easy. 1 Fe oxidizes by 1 ON up, 2 N reduces by 1 ON down each. so 1 O oxidizes 1 ON up. It directly leads to 4 Fe, 8 N and 1 O2, i.e 4 Fe(NO3)2 -> 2 Fe2O3 + 8 NO2 + O2. I remember solving such things in 1980, before entering high school.

eyeroll Take it easy. There's a few chatrooms on the site https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=chemistry.stackexchange.com but they aren't very actively used. You got more than enough rep. to use them. You'd see if people would want to talk.

Sometimes you have to balance other transient/virtual charged species along with electrons to get everything to click. In this answer involving aqueous redox with a weak acid (barium peroxide and hypochlorous acid), we treat the hydrogen ions as a virtual species along with the electrons precisely because we have only a weak acid, and balancing both leads in that case to the oxygen production being changed.
In this case the natural choice is oxide ions, which are necessary to get $\ce{Fe2O3}$. We can render three partial reactions involving different components of the initial ferrous nitrate:
$\ce{2Fe^{2+} + 3O^{2-} -> Fe2O3 + 2e^-}$
$\ce{2 NO3^- -> 2 NO2 + O2 + 2e^-}$
$\ce{O2 + 4e^- -> 2 O^{2-}}$
It becomes evident that to balance the oxide ions we must take the first partial reaction twice and the third one three times. This puts an excess of eight electrons on the left, which are balanced (without involving any more oxide ions) by taking the second partial reaction four times.
So add twice the first reaction, four times the second reaction and three times the third reaction. Since the second and third partial reactions involve $\ce{O2}$ on both sides, that needs to be cancelled out from the sum to identify the net oxygen production. We end with
$\underset{\ce{4 Fe(NO3)2}}{\underbrace{\ce{4 Fe^{2+} + 8 NO_3^-}}}\ce{->2 Fe2O3 + 8 NO2 + O2}$
